# What is the time complexity of converting a set of n integers to a list of n integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, time-complexity

```
my_set = {1,2,3,4}
my_list = list(my_set)
```

Is this going to take *O(n)* or *O(1)* ?

Comment: `my_set` isn't altered in any way, and `my_list` is a brand new object containing `n` items. I don't see why you think it *could* be O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the below results, the line `my_list = list(my_set)` is clearly *O(n)*.

```py
my_set = {1,2}
%timeit my_list = list(my_set)
my_set = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
%timeit my_list = list(my_set)
my_set = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
%timeit my_list = list(my_set)
```

output:

```py
403 ns ± 5.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
621 ns ± 77.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
905 ns ± 27.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```